# Using Excel files to create formatted Word files

Tags: excel, ms-word, software-design, file-conversion

I need to create a custom software that would convert Excel files to a formatted Word file.

From the Excel file below;

.[image]

To this word file with the given formatting.

Now I have not done any work in this before. But, I have a few ideas in using Python with CSV file formats but I am not sure. What can I do to write a software that could fully automate this process? For example, take the Excel file as an input and generate a formatted Word file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the csv module that comes with Python. The function csv.reader() will allow you to iterate through the lines of of your csv file. Additionally, pandas, another Python module (which you have to download) is also a good option when it comes to working with data. However, I'm fairly certain that it won't be automatic, and that you'll have to deal with converting that to a Word file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Excel formulas such as =Concatentate to gather the completed sentences onto a separate tab, named for example "Summary", in a named range such as "StudentInfo". Then close the spreadsheet.

In Word, use your skills to get the cursor to the correct spot, then try this:

```
Sub CopyNamedRangeFromExcelWorkbook()
     ' For this to work, must go to VB Editor and pick --> Tools > References > Miscorsoft Excel 15.0 Obj Lib
     Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
     Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
     xlApp.Visible = False

     Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
     Set xlWorkbook = _ 
         xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desdemona\Desktop\TheSpreadsheet.xlsx")
     xlWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("StudentInfo").Copy
     Selection.Paste ' pastes the excel data as a Word table
     xlWorkbook.Close
     xlApp.Quit
     ' now apply a format to the word table, or revert it to text, or whatever.
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is:

1. First, rearrange the data into tabular format, e.g., Name in column A, Gender in column B, etc. You could write a simple VBA routine to create a tabular file based on your raw file.
2. Use Word's mail merge feature to write the paragraphs by filling data fields from the Excel file.

Hope that helps.